Why is ros2 humble giving me odd lag when publishing camera feed?
What I'm doing:
I am attempting to create a ros2 system where an nvidia jetson orin uses opencv to get feed from a few cameras, and publish those frames to topics.  For testing though I've been running everything on my laptop, and am attempting to just get frames from my webcam, publish them to a topic, and then subscribe to that topic and display them.  I've included my nodes at the end for reference.  I think the publisher should be somewhat straight forward, and then for the subscriber I'm actually subscribed to the same topic 4 times just because I'm testing the system with only one camera currently, when ultimately I'll be displaying 4 separate camera feeds.
The Problem:
The system seems to work well with little to no lag for anywhere from 5 to 8 minutes, but then the feed gets very laggy.  After probably 5 minutes of lag though, the feed will go back to being fine.  I could tell that my publisher was running at a constant speed, so I thought that maybe the issue was with my subscriber node, so I tried viewing the feed in rviz, but I encountered the same problem.  After that I decided to log the ros time in the callback for both the publisher and subscriber, and then using those times I was able to find the time between each loop.  For the publisher, I consistently get about 33000000 nanoseconds.  When looking at the same thing for the subscriber though, it will be about the same for that 5 to 8 minutes, but then it will spike to anywhere between 53000000 and 250000000.  I don't know why this is happening, so any help would be much appreciated!
webcam_publisher.py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

import numpy as np

from cv_bridge import CvBridge

from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

import cv2
import pickle

# from std_msgs.msg import String

class CameraNotOpenError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "The camera was not able to open properly"

class CameraStoppedReadingError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "The camera has unexpectedly stopped returning frames"

class WebcamPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self, file):
        super().__init__('webcam_publisher')
        self.file = file
        self.publisher = self.create_publisher(Image, f'/cameras/raw/camera_0', 10)

        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            raise CameraNotOpenError

        timer_period = 1/60  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if not ret:
            raise CameraStoppedReadingError
        pickled_frame = pickle.dumps(frame)
        
        msg = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, "bgr8")
        
        self.publisher.publish(msg)
        print(f"time: {self.get_clock().now()} frame: {str(self.i)}", file=self.file)
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    with open("webcam_publisher.txt", "w") as f:
        webcam_publisher = WebcamPublisher(f)

        try:
            rclpy.spin(webcam_publisher)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            if isinstance(e, CameraStoppedReadingError):
                webcam_publisher.cap.release()
        finally:
            # Destroy the node explicitly
            # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
            # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
            webcam_publisher.destroy_node()
            rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

main.py (the subscriber node)
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from message_filters import Subscriber, TimeSynchronizer

import numpy as np

from pynput import keyboard

import cv2

import json

from cv_bridge import CvBridge

class PeacefulExit(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Closed node successfully"

class MainInterfaceNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, file0, file1, file2, file3):
        super().__init__("main_interface")

        self.file0 = file0
        self.file1 = file1
        self.file2 = file2
        self.file3 = file3

        self.count0 = self.count1 = self.count2 = self.count3 = 0
        
        self.camera_0 = self.camera_1 = self.camera_2 = self.camera_3 = 0

        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        self.camera_view = -1

        global video_display

        self.ts = None

        self.camera_0_subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, "/cameras/raw/camera_0", self.listener_callback0, 10)
        self.camera_1_subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, "/cameras/raw/camera_0", self.listener_callback1, 10)
        self.camera_2_subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, "/cameras/raw/camera_0", self.listener_callback2, 10)
        self.camera_3_subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, "/cameras/raw/camera_0", self.listener_callback3, 10)

    

    def listener_callback0(self, msg_0):
        global video_display
        global keys_down

        print(f"time: {self.get_clock().now()} frame: {self.count0}", file=self.file0)
        # Get frames and display them
        frame_0 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg_0, "bgr8")
        

        window_height = 1000

        
        camera_display_height = int(window_height/2)
        (h, w) = frame_0.shape[:2]
        new_w_0 = int((w/h)*camera_display_height)

        frame_0 = cv2.resize(frame_0, (new_w_0, camera_display_height))



        cv2.imshow("Camera Output0", frame_0)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        
        self.count0 += 1

    def listener_callback1(self, msg_0):
        global video_display
        global keys_down
        print(f"time: {self.get_clock().now()} frame: {self.count1}", file=self.file1)
        # Get frames and display them
        frame_0 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg_0, "bgr8")
        

        window_height = 1000

        
        camera_display_height = int(window_height/2)
        (h, w) = frame_0.shape[:2]
        new_w_0 = int((w/h)*camera_display_height)

        frame_0 = cv2.resize(frame_0, (new_w_0, camera_display_height))



        cv2.imshow("Camera Output1", frame_0)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        
        self.count1 += 1
    
    def listener_callback2(self, msg_0):
        global video_display
        global keys_down
        print(f"time: {self.get_clock().now()} frame: {self.count2}", file=self.file2)
        # Get frames and display them
        frame_0 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg_0, "bgr8")
        

        window_height = 1000

        
        camera_display_height = int(window_height/2)
        (h, w) = frame_0.shape[:2]
        new_w_0 = int((w/h)*camera_display_height)

        frame_0 = cv2.resize(frame_0, (new_w_0, camera_display_height))



        cv2.imshow("Camera Output2", frame_0)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        self.count2 += 1
        

    def listener_callback3(self, msg_0):
        global video_display
        global keys_down
        print(f"time: {self.get_clock().now()} frame: {self.count3}", file=self.file3)
        # Get frames and display them
        frame_0 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg_0, "bgr8")
        

        window_height = 1000

        
        camera_display_height = int(window_height/2)
        (h, w) = frame_0.shape[:2]
        new_w_0 = int((w/h)*camera_display_height)

        frame_0 = cv2.resize(frame_0, (new_w_0, camera_display_height))



        cv2.imshow("Camera Output3", frame_0)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        self.count3 += 1
    

def main(args=None):
    global video_display
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    with open("cam0reclog.txt", "w") as f0:
        with open("cam1reclog.txt", "w") as f1:
            with open("cam2reclog.txt", "w") as f2:
                with open("cam3reclog.txt", "w") as f3:
                    main_interface_node = MainInterfaceNode(f0, f1, f2, f3)

                    rclpy.spin(main_interface_node)
                        
                    main_interface_node.destroy_node()
                    rclpy.shutdown()
    
    print("Exited program successfully.  Have a nice day!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

